# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'IdJournal'

Tags: c#, razor, drop-down-menu

I found multiple posts about this issue on Stack Overflow but none with an answer that fix the problem I have.

I have a view with a dropdownlist that display the item label of journal from table in Database : Journal : id, label
Here is the code of the view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {            
        <input style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" type="file" name="file" id="upload"/>
         <input type="text" name="journal" value="test"/>

        <input type="submit" style="margin-left:40px;cursor:pointer;" id="load" value="Upload"/>

                  @Html.DropDownList("IdJournal")
                     }
```

And my controller is :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string journal, long IdJournal)
    {

        ScanITAPP.Service.ImageRender service = new Service.ImageRender();
        service.UploadImageToDB(file, journal, IdJournal);



        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        return PartialView("Form");
    }

    //DropdownList
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new Bd_scanitEntities();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.JournalSet
          .Select(c => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = c.Id.ToString(),
              Text = c.label
          });
        ViewBag.IdJournal = items;
        //ViewData["IdJournal"] = items;

        return View();
    }
```

The code is for uploading and image and associate it to a "Journal" , after executing the code I get the image with the Journal_id in my Dtabse but but it throws an error : There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Id'. I don't know what's the problem please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by editing my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file, string journal, long IdJournal)
{    
    var db = new Bd_scanitEntities();
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.JournalSet
      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
      {
          Value = c.Id.ToString(),
          Text = c.label
      });
    ViewBag.IdJournal = items;

    ScanITAPP.Service.ImageRender service = new Service.ImageRender();
    service.UploadImageToDB(file, journal, IdJournal);



    return View();
}
```

Comment: also mention what change you did